# "Unmerge" upstream branch by resetting origin and then merging

Tags: git, github

I am having a problem reverting a merge I made into an upstream branch, to which I do not have direct write access.

I made some changes locally, pushed them to origin, and had them merged by a fellow team member into our upstream repository. Now I want to revert those changes, essentially "unmerge" the merge. So far, I have:

1. Reverted my local repository to the correct commit using `git reset --hard *commit number*`
2. Force push this reset to origin using `git push --force origin *branch name*`

Currently, my remote repository is updated to show none of the commits that I have reverted, which is correct. However, when I try to merge these changes into upstream, essentially "unmerging" my previous merge, GitHub shows that there are no differences between the specified branch of my remote repository and the same branch of the upstream respository. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Note: I tried adding a new line to a file, thus showing that there is some change between the branches, and then merging, but this did not work.

Comment: If this merge was done via Pull Request from the forked repo into the upstream repo, can you request your fellow team member to *Revert the PR merge.*